# How to ensure the calling instance is passed to a parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, parameter-passing

```
class BaseCaller
{
    protected internal void DoBaseSpecificStuff()
    {
    }
}  

class Caller : BaseCaller
{
    Reciever.DoStuffWithCaller(this);
}

class Reciever
{
    public static DoStuffWithCaller(BaseCaller callerInstance)
    {
        callerInstance.DoBaseSpecificStuff()
        // Extract stuff from BaseCaller after method has been called
    }
}
```

What would be the way to ensure the Caller always invokes Reciever.DoStuffWithCaller with a reference to itself as shown in the example and not another Caller instance.
I know this might be done by using StackFrame and not having the parameter at all, but I´m looking for a simpler, maintainable and more performant solution. C#.. Thx...

EDIT: ( see comments )  In Reciever I need access to instance specific logic inside BaseCaller before proceeding, but would like to reuse Reciever.DoStuffWithCaller on different derived classes (direct callers). An extension method  on BaseCaller makes me do this.DoStuffWithCaller() from within Caller but does not address the question as any other BaseCaller instance could call DoStuffWithCaller(). From comments it seems like I should make an intermediate derived class with the DoStuffWithCaller() method?

Comment: There's no way and the fact that a method needs to know it's caller is a code smell. It's a cyclic dependency between caller and callee.

Comment: there is a dirty way. send a bool behind Caller which tells its called with `this` or not

Comment: Maybe you need to ask yourself if the functionality in the `DoStuffWIthCaller` should actually be inside of `Caller`.

Comment: @juharr Sorry.. My definition of the problem was not clear. Please see edit.  I guess an extension method is the obvious answer?

Comment: If you don't control `Caller` then how is your method getting used in it, or at least I assume that was your meaning (technically the code will not compile since the call to `DoStuffWIthCaller` isn't in a method and that method doesn't even have a return type)

Comment: You want this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx

Comment: @juharr Sorry again and thanks for comments.. Trying to be generic in my answer moved me away from the specific problem.. What a bugger.. Please see edit..

Comment: @code4life  this will only give me a reference to the file the type is defined in..

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. There is no way to force at the call site some code to use `this` instead of any other valid value of a given type for calling a method. There are mechanisms (such as inspecting the stack, as you suggest) to identify the caller and verify/use the desired reference. But a) it's not clear why it should matter to `DoStuffWithCaller()` whether the caller passes itself or something else to the method, and b) your comment about using an extension method makes me wonder how you think that would address the problem in any way at all. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho agree 100%.. I´m having a hard time specifying the real question.. I gave it another try in the EDIT.

Comment: @usr I´m beginning to see your point.. Thx..

Comment: An extension method does not require use of `this` any more than any other method would. You can just as easily write `someOtherCallerInstance.DoStuffWithCaller()` instead of `this.DoStuffWithCaller()`. Without a more concrete code example that shows clearly what it is in `DoStuffWithCaller()` that motivates your desire to impose this constraint, I don't see a way to answer the question in a useful way. In general, a method that takes an instance of some type should be able to deal with _any_ instance of that type, and not care from what context the method was called.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Did you read the edit?

Comment: Yes, of course I did. That's why my comment responded to your description of how you (mistakenly) think an extension method accomplishes your goal. Unfortunately, your edit does not make the question clear enough for me to understand it.